# Formal Definition of differentiable

Tags: calculus

Given
\begin{align*}
y(x) =\begin{cases} \int^x_0 \frac{e^{e^t}}{e^x} dt \ &\mbox{for} \ x > 0 \\
   a + bx + cx^2                                 &\mbox{for} \ x \leq 0 \end{cases}
\end{align*}

I am trying to use the formal definition of limit,

$f$ is differentiable in $x = x_0$ if the limit
\begin{align*}
f'(c) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h} = m \ \mbox{exist}.
\end{align*}
to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable. So far I've written that y must satisfy \begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_-} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0_+} = \frac{y(x) - y(0)}{x - 0}
\end{align*}
and calculated that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_-} &y(x) = a\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+} &y(x) \ \mbox{gives} \ \frac{0}{0} \ \mbox{form, so I used L'Hôpitals rule again}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
y'(x)= \begin{cases}  \frac{e^{e^x}}{e} \ &\mbox{for} \ x > 0 \ \mbox{(by the fundmental theorem of calculus)}\\
 2cx + b   \ &\mbox{for} \ x \leq 0 \end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+} y(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+} \frac{e^{e^x}}{e} = 1    \ ( => a \ \mbox{must be} \ = 1)
\end{align*}

And I have found that $f(x)$ is continous in $x = 0$ because
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} y(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} a + bx + cx^2 = a = f(0).
\end{align*}
Now, trying to use the formal definition of differentiable:

\begin{align*}
 f'(0) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \\
      &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_0^h \frac{e^{e^t}}{eh} dt - a}{h}  \\
      &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_0^h \frac{e^{e^t}}{eh}dt - 1}{h} |\cdot eh \\
      &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\int_0^h e^{e^t}dt - eh}{eh^2}
\end{align*}

But I dont know how to proceed from here. I tried getting rid of the integral, and ended up with
\begin{align*}
f'(0) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{[e^{e^0} - e^{e^0}] - eh}{eh^2} \ \mbox{(Direct substitution for} \ h = 0) \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{[e^1 - e^1] - eh}{eh^2}\\
&= \lim_{h-\rightarrow 0} \frac{0 - eh}{eh^2}= \frac{-1}{h} 
\end{align*}
And I know this doesn't work because I get zero in the denominator. I appreciate all help I can get!

Comment: I have upvoted your question but it contains some major typos in the latter half

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I am still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $\lim_{x\to0^+}y(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{e^x}\int_0^xe^{e^t}dt=\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^xe^{e^t}dt=0$ since $e^x\to1^+$. It does not have the $0/0$ form. This gives $\color{red}{f(0)=a=0}$ for continuity.
- $y'(x)$ is not $e^{e^x}/e$ for $x>0$. $$\begin{align*}y(x)&=e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{e^t}dt\\y'(x)&=-e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{e^t}dt+e^{-x}\times e^{e^x}\\&=e^{-x}\left[e^{e^x}-\int_0^xe^{e^t}dt\right]\\&=e^{e^x-x}-y(x)\end{align*}$$by the product rule.
- Left hand derivative at $0$ is $b$. Right hand derivative is given by$$\begin{align*}\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{y(h)-y(0)}h&=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^he^{e^t}dt}{he^h}\\&=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^{e^h}}{e^h(1+h)}\\&=e\end{align*}$$giving $\color{blue}{b=e}$ for differentiability. Note that this limit has the $0/0$ form.